# How can I detect URL parameter changes in WKWebView?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

The html file of the the URL always remain as **index.html** but it has extra parameters like:

> index.html#/main/curriculum/9/currID=a48fasdf8e0ce4461c9d6469ee642e4fb1&expand=false

The `didFinishNavigation` is only fired when the main page is changed but it can not detect the parameter changes.

Is there a way I can try?

Answer (score 0):

try it with :

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
   didCommitNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation;
```